# Fixed Point Iteration is Not Converging to the Desired Root

Tags: numerical-methods

What is the fixed point for the following function?
$f(x) = 2sin(\pi x) + x = 0$ between $[1,2]$

I expressed $f(x)$ as $x=g(x)$ such that $g(x)$ can be $- 2sin(\pi x)$ or $\frac{1}{\pi}sin^{-1}(\frac{-x}{2})$. However, in both cases, the method is not coverging to a root lying between in the interval $[1, 2]$. What to do? Please help me.

Comment: Are you looking over a particular range?

Comment: yes between [1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $1 \le x \le 2$, you don't want the principal branch of arcsin.  You
could try $x = 2 + \dfrac{\arcsin(-x/2)}{\pi}$ (for the solution in $[1.5,2]$, or
$x = 1 + \dfrac{\arcsin(x/2)}{\pi}$ (for the solution in $[1,1.5]$).

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is the visual interpretation of @Robert Israel's answer.
Captured from my old exercise book ($\epsilon$ used is $0.0005$).
[image: Fixed-point-iteration-example]
Basically, the problem lies within how we truncate the sine-shaped graph when we draw arcsine graph $y = \frac{1}{\pi} sin^{-1}(-\pi/2)$, while in fact we are solving an equation involving sine, that is, $2sin(\pi x)+x=0 $. The $y_1$ and $y_2$ in the picture above is the "extended version" of the arcsine graph.

Comment: Please write down the answers instead of posting images

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite, as you did, as $\sin(\pi x)=-\frac{x}{2}$.

Then $\pi x=\pi +\arcsin(x/2)$ leads to one of the  solutions.